# Dojo Ajax Example Code Fails in My Dijit Button with 500 Sever Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I was moving right along with getting my digit dialog with a form to work. My latest addition was a test Ajax request. My code wasn't working so I cut and pasted the code from a [dojo website article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/ajax/). When I embed it in my working dijit button, I get the error:

> 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'request.post')

This what I copied:

```
require(["dojo/request"], function(request){
request.post("post-content.php", {
    data: {
        color: "blue",
        answer: 42
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Something": "A value"
    }
}).then(function(text){
    console.log("The server returned: ", text);
});
});
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
require(["dojo/dom",
        "dijit/Dialog",
        "dijit/form/Form",
        "dijit/form/TextBox",
        "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
        "dijit/form/Textarea",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojox/validate/web",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
function(dom, Dialog, Form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button, request){

    alertDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "Email Result",
        content: "<p>No Content</p>",
        sytle: "width 30em"
    });

    emailDialog = new Dialog({
        title: "Email Form",
        content: dom.byId("emailFormHTML").textContent,
        style: "width: 50em"
    });

    emForm = new Form({
        /*onSubmit: function(){
            return this.validate();
        }*/
    },"contact-form");

    toText = new TextBox({
        readOnly: "readOnly",
        value: "Staff"
    },"to");

    nameText = new ValidationTextBox({
        placeholder: "Your Name",
        required: "true",
        missingMessage: "We'd like to know who you are."
    },"name");

    emailText = new ValidationTextBox({
        placeholder: "Your email",
        validator: dojox.validate.isEmailAddress,
        invalidMessage: "This is not a valid email address!"
    },"email");

    messageText = new TextArea({
        placeholder: "Your message"
    },"message");

    sendBtn = new Button({
        label: "Send",
        onClick: function(){
            if (emForm.validate() == true){
                emailDialog.hide();
                request.post("send-message.php", {
                    data: {
                        color: "blue",
                        answer: 42
                    },
                    headers: {
                        "X-Something": "A value"
                    }
                }).then(function(text){
                        console.log("The server returned: ", text);
                    });
            }
        }
    },"submit-btn");
});

require(["dojo/dom",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(dom, Button)
{
    var showEmailBtn = new Button({
    onClick: function(){
        toText.set("value","Executive Director");
        emailDialog.show(); } },
    "showEmail");
});
</script>
```

The only thing I changed was the name of the php file. I have a feeling it has something to do the function header, but I can't see it.

**Update**

I think I fixed one problem and caused another. I changed the function header to:

```
    require(["dojo/dom",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/dom-form",
        "dijit/Dialog",
        "dijit/form/Form",
        "dijit/form/TextBox",
        "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
        "dijit/form/Textarea",
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojox/validate/web",
        "dojo/domReady!"],
function(dom, request, domForm, Dialog, Form, TextBox, ValidationTextBox, TextArea, Button ){
```

That eliminated the first error. If this is the correct way to declare the header, I'd like to know what the rules are. Apparently things must be in some sort of order.

Now I get the error:

> Network Issue
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

This is in Safari. I have another test page on same website that does AJAX just fine.

When I tried it in Firefox, I got this error on the console:

> [23:24:20.081] The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. @ http://test.loc/dojodialog/index.php

Does there have to be a properly formatted header? I haven't seen it in any examples.

**Answer**

Dumb programming error. It was an error in the php file. I had copied another php file and edited out what I didn't need. I didn't notice that I left a closing bracket so the php execution failed. Now I know to look at my server side code if I get the 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be several reasons for a 500 error. One of them is that the sever program being invoked has a programming error and fails. In my case, I left a closing bracket when removing extra code.